# Serving two static files in django

Tags: django

My project structure is as follows:

```
project:
       -> static 
                -> js
                    ->project.js
                -> images
                   -> project.png
       -> templates.
       -> project
       -> app1 
              -> static
                       ->js
                            -> custom.js
                       -> images
                            -> some.png
              -> template.
```

So i have project js and images and custom images and js for an app 
Basically when i am using

```
 script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/custom.js"> </script>
```

for my app templates. 
it's not picking custom.js.

How can i fix it. keeping custom.js in my project js works.

Comment: What is `STATICFILES_FINDERS` set to in settings.py?

Comment: 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

Comment: Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Can you show us all static files settings?

Comment: It's good practice to namespace your static content by including the app name. For example `app1/static/app1/js`.

Comment: What's the value of `DEBUG` and is `app1` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Did you define STATIC_URL in setting.py